# Javascript, providing arguement alternatives

Tags: javascript, html5

Is this bad coding?  Is it OK to use 'OR' to specify argument alternatives?

```
        // This function will throw an error if it has no arguements and local stroage is not available
        var buildLoginUrl = function(username, password, account)
        {       
            var user = username || localStorage.getItem("username"),
                pass = password || localStorage.getItem("password"),
                acco = account  || localStorage.getItem("account");

            var url = SERVER + "Login.aspx?"
                + "Account=" + acco
                    + "&Name=" + user
                        + "&Password=" + pass;

            return url;
        }
```

**Update**

This question is about the practicalities of using 'OR' to specify alternative arguments. **NOT** about the mass of security flaws associated with the Login example I provided.  It was just a quick example.  I would change the example in the question but it would be unfair to the answers already provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DO NOT DO THIS

A minor issue is that this will not function properly if someone provides a blank string such as account = "" AND localStorage does not exist.

A larger one is that you're not encoding any special characters here meaning that spaces, ampersands, question marks, etc. would be off limits even for the password. You need to use something like [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to encode properly (but see below first)

A much more major issue is how you're treating passwords

- The password is in the url so anyone along the HTTP routing chain will be able to easily spoof the user.
- The password and the username is in the url and it is likely the user reuses their password/username combos. ***You are exposing them to having many of their other accounts stolen.***
- The password is stored in localStorage so anyone who sits down at the computer after your user will be able to log in as them simply by not supplying a password parameter.
- If you're ever routing to that url then the user's username/password is visible in their url bar for anyone who walks by.

  - If the user ever copy-pastes that url into an email they just inadvertently shared their password with the world.
- [Vulnerabilities in localStorage might expose your user information to attackers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718349/html5-localstorage-security)

A login changes system state and should therefore be a POST operation and the values should be supplied via POST parameters. It should also be done over https.

You should rely on your browser to store the login data. All major browsers have some sort of automatic detection for login forms and password lockers. The standard authorization technique is that once a user logs in your return an authorization cookie that allows them to authenticate themselves to the sever for a given amount of time. You can set that time to be infinite (though it is not recommended). Whatever framework you're using (looks like asp.net?) already has built in support for this, you just need to research how to do it.

While we're add it, you know about [salting and hashing and not storing passwords in plain text, right](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers George (the password is md5 encrypted when it's sent - although I didn't show it, and stored using AES) and the username and account cannot contain any special characters or white-space at this point.  The question was more to do with the way the arguements or lack of are handled.  Interesting point about localStorage and public computers.  The application is mainly for mobile devices - which should be personal (but very well could be shared)

Comment: Also, this is for logging into a webservice

Comment: @CrimsonChin I don't think you should ever be passing your login information via GET requests, it can get stored in browser history, be intercepted and simply doesn't make sense. As or MD5 - it is listed as 'severely compromised': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security
Security is hard to get right. Use what is built in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649362.aspx